# Remove virtual serialport (socat)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, socat

I have created two virtual serial ports on my ubuntu-notebook.

-> sudo socat /dev/ttyUSB7 /dev/ttyUSB8

Now I want to remove the serial ports and the connection between them.

I can't find the command to do that.

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

Thanks!

Comment: just guessing, `/bin/rm -f /dev/ttyUSB7`, OR `/bin/unlink /dev/ttyUSB7` . Else check `man socat` and see if there are any likely suspects under the `See Also` section. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I also searched through the Internet to find out a solution, but if you want you can permanently remove socket with using "sudo apt-get remove socat" command on ubuntu. this will remove all the virtually created ports.

Answer (score 0):

`socat` — creates temporary file-sockets for network connections. When you stop the utility from executing all connections and sockets are closed.
If they remain, it is just a glitch — you may remove sockets with `sudo rm -f <file>`
If you running `socat` in the background — just stop it with `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

With the command you show Socat creates two files, not devices or sockets, and terminates immediately.

Remove the (empty) files:

`rm /dev/ttyUSB7 /dev/ttyUSB8`